# CSS has suddenly disappeared - No explanation (1.9)

Tags: theme, css

I was doing some final finishing touches to a Magento 1.9 installation, refresh the page, and magically all the styles, apart from those that are inline, have stopped working.

On inspection, Magento is calling for `skin/frontend/base/default/css/styles.css` and there isn't a file there. (403 Error) I have checked in a previous backup, and the file wasn't there either, and I am using custom theme (Smartwave Mango > http://themeforest.net/item/mango-responsive-magento-theme/11629375?s_phrase=&s_rank=157), so I presume it shouldn't be looking there

I can't work out why magento is trying to find `styles.css` from that folder at all. I have changed **no** CSS since yesterday, only a static block, so nothing has been edited.

Things I have tried:

- Cleared all Caches, multiple times (Browser + Magento)
- Cleared Indexes
- Verified the base URL is correct
- Checked a backup to see if files have somehow got lost- can't see any change
- Looked for a replacement styles.css- it doesn't exist.
- Checked in Chrome + FF
- Checked that Magento is using the correct theme

It does seem that Magento is ignoring my `local.xml` in `app/design/frontend/smartwave/mango/layout`, and putting default references in the Head of the generated HTML, but being a noob, am not sure. Images are loading, but custom JS isn't either.

(Almost) tearing hair out here- thanks for any help!

Comment: "Cleared all Caches, multiple times" - did you also try to delete the entire "var" folder? (make sure you don't need anything from there first, like logs or maybe magento connect package settings!)

Comment: @Ness, no, I didn't. I'll take a look. Lil bit scared of doing that.

Comment: you can just rename the dir. same as deleting, without the delete part ;)

Comment: @Ness Made no difference, I'm afraid

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I left it for a day and refreshed everything.

Works perfectly and reliably.

Magento works in mysterious ways!

Answer (score 1):

You should also check if you have the right ***template package*** set. In your case I supose it should be '***smartwave***'.

Does your template use sass or less for styling?

Comment: I believe that I have, but where should I check?

Comment: Nope, Vanilla CSS

Comment: System->Configuration->General->Design->Package